# The variable doesn't change outside of the closure

Tags: swift

```
var arrayLength:Int = 0 // is equal to 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let urlPath = "http://example.com/json"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in

        if (error? != nil) {
            println(error)
        } else {
            var jsonResponse: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

            let json = JSON(jsonResponse!)
            self.arrayLength = json["dump"].array?.count as Int!
            println("Second: \(self.arrayLength)") // is equal to 3

            for postIndex in 0...self.arrayLength-1 {
                println(json["dump"][postIndex]["title"])
            }
        }

    })
    task.resume()

    println(arrayLength) // is equal to 0 again
```

I set the

```
var arrayLength:Int = 0
```

in the beginning of code. Later inside of the viewDidLoad() I changed it to 3. And when I call it, outside of the task block it again equal to 0. What is the problem here and what I do wrong?

Comment: You are printing it before it finishes the asynchronous task. In other words the download started but didn't finish

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're changing your `arrayLength`var inside your closure. The *problem* you're facing here it's just normal way of how threads work.

1. When `viewDidLoad`starts you're on the Main Thread
2. the line `let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ...` defines a new task, that's not yet executing
3. `task.resume()` launches this task on another thread. This is going to take some time to finish. When it's finished your `arrayLength` will be changed
4. immediately you're asking on the main thread for your `arrayLength` value

Here:

```
     println(arrayLength) // is equal to 0 again
```

it's not that arrayLength is equal to 0 *again*, you haven't given enough time to your task to execute and change that value.

**EDIT: if you need to check arrayLength after the closure finishes...**

Just create a function and call it last thing inside your closure. Like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in

        if (error? != nil) {
            println(error)
        } else {
            var jsonResponse: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

            let json = JSON(jsonResponse!)
            self.arrayLength = json["dump"].array?.count as Int!
            println("Second: \(self.arrayLength)") // is equal to 3

            for postIndex in 0...self.arrayLength-1 {
                println(json["dump"][postIndex]["title"])
            }

            functionToDoSomethingAtTheEndOfTheClosure();
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}

func functionToDoSomethingAtTheEndOfTheClosure() {
  // this is going to be executed at the end of the closure's code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for describing! So, how can I do that it will print it just after the task process? Must I turn off asynchronous or the other way is here?

Comment: Call the relevant line of code in the completion block itself.

Comment: @NeilHorton but I want to call it outside of this block

Comment: @NeilHorton is right. Updated answer to show you an example